# MIPS sum of all the values in an array

Tags: assembly, mips

so I have an array with 5 values that the user enters and I need to find and print the sum of all five values. This is my code right now.

```
    main:
        la      $a1, ARRAY

        # print out message one
        li      $v0,4
        la      $a0,msg1
        syscall

        #make counter
        li      $t1,5
        li      $t0,5
LOOP:
        #print out number prompt
        li      $v0,4
        la      $a0,msg2
        syscall

        #read in int
        li      $v0,5
        syscall
        mtc1    $v0,$f0 #convert into to float
        cvt.s.w $f0,$f0
        s.s     $f0,($a1)

        #repeat loop and move to next array spot
        addiu   $a1,$a1,4
        addiu   $t1,$t1,-1
        bne     $t1,$zero,LOOP

        la      $a1,ARRAY

        #print list header
        li      $v0,4
        la      $a0,msg3
        syscall
       PRINT:
        #print array
        l.s     $f12,0($a1)
        li      $v0,2
        syscall

        #print new line
        lb      $a0,EOL
        li      $v0,11
        syscall
        lb      $a0,EOL
        li      $v0,11
        syscall

        #move loop one
        addiu   $a1,$a1,4
        addiu   $t0,$t0,-1
        bne     $t0,$zero,PRINT

        #print sum message
        li      $v0,4
        la      $a0,msg4
        syscall

        #create counter
        li      $t2,5
        li      $s6,0

        la      $a1,ARRAY

SUM:
        la      $t3,ARRAY($t2)
        addu    $s6,$s6,$t3

        #loop it until 5 have been added
        addiu   $a1,$a1,4
        addiu   $t2,$t2,-1
        bne     $t2,$zero,SUM
        
li      $v0,1
        la      $a0,($s6)
        syscall


        #end program
        jr $ra
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question or explain exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry! I have code for the summation of the array but It's not working right so I'm looking for help finding my error it gives me an exception 4 error. I'm a very basic beginner, so it may be something very obvious.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.